# Separation in infinite dimensional normed space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I would like to construct some counterexamples:

- $E$ is an infinite dimensional normed space. Let $C, D$ be nonempty convex subsets in $E$ such that
  $$
  C\cap D=\emptyset.
  $$
  There is no vector $f\in E^*\setminus \{0\}$ and $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$ such that
  $$
  f(x)\leq \alpha\leq f(y) \quad \forall x\in C, \quad \forall y\in D.
  $$
- $E$ is an infinite dimensional normed space. Let $C, D$ be nonempty convex subsets in $E$ such that
  $$
  C\cap D=\emptyset
  $$
  and $C$ is compact.
  There is no vector $f\in E^*\setminus\{0\}$ and $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$ such that
  $$
  f(x)< \alpha< f(y)  \quad\forall x\in C, \quad \forall y\in D.
  $$

Thank you for all comments and helping.

Comment: For the first bullet point [see this thread on mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/37551/). For the second start with the closed unit disk $C$ and $D = \{y \gt 1\}$.